# В IE9 некорректно отображается градиент

Tags: html, css, css3, internet-explorer, градиент

В IE9 некорректно отображается градиент.

```
<div id="top_menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="home.html">Главная</a></li>
            <li class="first_wrap"><a href="#">Подобрать персонал</a>
                <ul class="second">
                    <li><a href="#">О нас</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Задать вопрос</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Это интересно</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Отзывы</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Цены</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">оставить <br> заявку</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">оставить резюме</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">контакты</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v8jrL46b/

Answer (score 1):

Старые IE ниже 10 версии не понимают свойство `linear-gradient`, для них есть специальное свойство `DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient.`

Для ІЕ 10+ уже используется префикс `-ms-linear-gradient`

Например:

```css
div {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1e5799 0%, #2989d8 52%, #7db9e8 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(to bottom, #1e5799 0%, #2989d8 52%, #7db9e8 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8', GradientType=0);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Подробнее [тут](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) или [тут](https://robertnyman.com/2010/02/15/css-gradients-for-all-web-browsers-without-using-images/)

Answer (score 1):

Задавайте градиент в старых `ИЕ` с помощью `filter`:

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  background: rgb(233, 192, 135);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(233, 192, 135, 1) 0%, rgba(176, 120, 43, 1) 45%, rgba(119, 71, 11, 1) 75%, rgba(131, 76, 11, 1) 86%, rgba(164, 103, 31, 1) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(233, 192, 135, 1) 0%, rgba(176, 120, 43, 1) 45%, rgba(119, 71, 11, 1) 75%, rgba(131, 76, 11, 1) 86%, rgba(164, 103, 31, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(233, 192, 135, 1) 0%, rgba(176, 120, 43, 1) 45%, rgba(119, 71, 11, 1) 75%, rgba(131, 76, 11, 1) 86%, rgba(164, 103, 31, 1) 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e9c087', endColorstr='#a4671f', GradientType=0);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(233, 192, 135, 1) 0%, rgba(176, 120, 43, 1) 45%, rgba(119, 71, 11, 1) 75%, rgba(131, 76, 11, 1) 86%, rgba(164, 103, 31, 1) 100%);
```

Добавил после скобок `to top` вместо `to bottom` и стало отображаться корректно.